# Minikube stopped to work on WSL (DRV_CREATE_TIMEOUT)

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubectl, minikube, wsl-2

**Update!**

**The issue was due Windows Fast Startup. After disabling it, turning off and on the computer it finally worked again.**

---

I installed kubectl and minikube on WSL and was using it to learn kubernetes and it was working fine until I disabled host autogeneration.

Next time I tried `minikube start` I saw errors, then I noticed kubectl was also complaining about client.cert and client.key, which is not present anywhere in `~/.minikube` folder.

What I tried so far based on stackoverflow questions:

- `minikube delete` and then `minikube start`
- `rm -rf $HOME/.minikube` and then `minikube start`
- `docker system prune`
- `minikube update-context`
- Delete all k8s images in docker

I enabled the host autogeneration again and restarted the system but I still have errors.

OS used:

- Windows 11 with WSL 2 (Ubuntu 22.04)

---

Log from `kubectl version`:
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.3", GitCommit:"9e644106593f3f4aa98f8a84b23db5fa378900bd", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-03-15T13:40:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7

The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

---

Log from last `minikube start`:

minikube v1.30.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 (amd64)

✨  Automatically selected the docker driver

Using Docker driver with root privileges

❗  For an improved experience it's recommended to use Docker Engine instead of Docker Desktop.
Docker Engine installation instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/#server

Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube

Pulling base image ...

Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...

✋  Stopping node "minikube"  ...

Powering off "minikube" via SSH ...

Deleting "minikube" in docker ...

StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...

Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

❌  Exiting due to DRV_CREATE_TIMEOUT: Failed to start host: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

Suggestion: Try 'minikube delete', and disable any conflicting VPN or firewall software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyper-V is not available on Windows 11 Home edition, assuming you are using docker with container.

The `DRV_CREATE_TIMEOUT` error is typically caused by network issues and hyper-v issues. If you are still using hyper-v, change it to docker as hyper-V is only available on windows 11 Pro version.

Check the Kubernetes context using the command `kubectl config get-contexts` to see a list of available contexts. Make sure that the context you are trying to use is set as the current context with the command `kubectl config use-context <context>`.

As you have already used the docker system prune which removes all unused containers, images.It’s better to reinstall both Minikube and kubectl to ensure that they are properly configured freshly. You can also refer to the [blog](https://ssharizal.medium.com/minikube-on-windows-11-home-edition-with-wsl-2-workaround-267536731402) written by Syed Sharizal and another [blog](https://juwo.blogspot.com/) authored by Ani Philip which will help in overcoming the issue.

Comment: I removed minikube and kubectl from /usr/local/bin/ and also ~/.kube and ~/.minikube and installed them again, but it still not working. I use windows 11 pro, but now and even before I was using docker desktop integrated with WSL by default.

Comment: Can you try using hyper-v as you are using Windows 11 pro. Attaching [installation guide](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-11/ba-p/3745905#:~:text=Step%202%3A%20Enable%20Hyper%2DV%20on%20Windows%2011&text=Type%20appwiz.cpl%20and%20press,the%20box%20next%20to%20it.&text=Click%20on%20OK%20and%20wait%20for%20the%20installation%20process%20to%20complete.). If the issue is still persisting better ask in [docker for windows](https://forums.docker.com/c/docker-desktop-for-windows/48) community.

Comment: Hey Sai, I finally found the issue. Turns out that the issue was with Windows Fast Startup, after disabling it I turned off and on the computer and now it is working again. Gosh, 3 days struggling.

Comment: I appreciate your help here